# VBA: How to open an existing IE(8) Instance correctly without worrying to loose the Session

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-8

How to open an existing IE Instance correctly without worrying to loose the Session loaded?

This is how i do:

```
Dim Webbrowser
Webbrowser = 1
Set WebBrowser1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
WebBrowser1.Visible = False 
WebBrowser1.Navigate Link, Flags, TargetFrame, PostData, Headers
  While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Wend
```

but in some cases an existing IE(8) Instance does not load with Session Data

Background:
I have 7 Machines which are running Windows 7 64 Bit, IE8 and Access 2000
5 of them are able to access to the actual IE8 Session via InternetExplorer.Application Object in VBA (Access 2000). But 2 of them can't do that. I can't find the difference. All Versions are exactly the same. 
Behavior is same as i would use IE greater that IE8

Comment: isn't this more of a super user question?

Comment: what do you mean with super user? All Users are on the 7 Machines are "made" same way.

Comment: If you are having trouble with a programming question, then feel free to ask on SO. However this seems to be more of a hardware question, therefore i suggest you post it on http://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: ah, ok, i thought this may be an Object declaration or Software issue

Comment: btw. This is not a harware issue because a can duplicate this error by moving the Installation Image to an other Machine

Comment: It does not change the fact that this does not belong here on SO.

Comment: In tis current state, it won't probably ever get an answer

Comment: edited to make the question  a programming question...